# List of features introduces in each Javascript version

Tags: javascript, version, documentation, ecma

I'm trying to find an official documentation of the features introduced in each Javascript (ecma) version.
The best I could find so far is this:
[compat table es2016plus](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/)
and [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_2017.asp)

And maybe this one:
[ecma262](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-intro)
In the introduction section is a brief overview over the introduced features of the ecma versions. But I'm missing padStart and padEnd for the String.

But is there really no official document that lists the features introduced in which version?

Comment: https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_new-javascript-features.html

Comment: According to the w3schools page you linked, `padStart` amd `padEnd` both got introduced in the 2017 release. I don't know of any specific documentation - but considering some browsers support some bits while others don't, you're better off looking at the compatibility of specific functions; rather than looking for the implementation date.

Comment: [Here's the MDN documentation for `padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) which, for FF, was introduced in v48. We're currently on v93 or there abouts.